# Function reports back to a page after a foreach loop (in PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, loops, foreach, progress-bar

I am writing a foreach loop which will parse directories/subdirectories/files and search and replace values in the files based on a huge array.
This will take some time....probably around 10 minutes...And i was wondering **if there is a way with PHP, AJAX maybe, that when i go to the page that it will show me this (for example)**:

**There are X number of values left.**

and that number will decrease on every loop the foreach finishes.

So basically i have:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
   {do stuff here}
  }
 $param--; // to report back to the page
}
```

Comment: Make a question for this post

Comment: oops..it got erased when i made that code...sorry will edit it now. Edit: here i highlighted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to do it really. You could store it in the database, and simply have the section of the page show you the number you are after. You'd have to add the query to change the number in the `foreach` as well. So say you do it like this:

```
<?php 
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$getnum = $db->query("SELECT Num FROM mytable WHERE Jobtime = '$now'");
$result = $getnum->fetch();
$whatyouwant = $result['Num'];

if($whatyouwant > 0) { ?>

<p class="whatyouwant" id="whatyouwant"> <?php echo $whatyouwant;?> </p>

<?php } ?>
```

And change your `foreach` to do something like:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
   {do stuff here}
  }
 $updatestuff = $db->query("UPDATE mytable SET Num = '$param' WHERE Jobtime = '$now'");
}
```

The downside to this is you have to reload the page to get the info. To bypass this, you can have the first part of my answer ran in AJAX. So you would do:

```
var reloadFunction = function () {
     $.get("getnum.php", function (result) {
         $('#holdingwhatyouwant').html(result);
     });
 };
$(document).ready(function () {
     reloadFunction();
     setInterval(reloadFunction, 10000);
   });
```

If you do this, you need to mark the place for it on your page, such as:

`<div id="holdingwhatyouwant"></div>`

Why? Due to limitations. If you use the first method, and put that code on the page, you need to reload the page to see the update. If you use ajax only (similar to what I wrote here), you need to keep the page open for it to work, as well as have a handler (ajax needs to send data to php to be able to know the progress etc, so ajax has to trigger you function). Using them combined, it's all good. If you reload the page you get information instantly, if you don't, you'll get it every 10 seconds. Mind the 10000 interval expressed in milliseconds. Mind that you don't need the `if` part of the php, as it will return and empty paragraph.

Comment: Well thats what happens if you are in front of the computer 12h doing loops lol.
Thanks for the answer...i cant believe i didnt think of databases T_T

Comment: Hahah don't sweat it, it happens man =) I tend to sit and look at the problem for hours before I go ahead and just write it in the database :D